# Printing attributes from class/object files

Tags: python-3.x

Still in 'my infancy' from a coding capability perspective, I recently did a simple class/object context. Don't know how to print details from more than one attribute, looking for assistance here.

Working on a Windows PC in my attempt to get wiser on Python 3, I created a student.py and object.py. The former contains self.'s while the latter lists actual characteristics of student1, student2....studentn. Yet I seem only to be able to print `student1.gpa`, `student1.major` and a number of other student1 characteristics for THAT student only. How do I print more than student1 characteristics?

## Student.py

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, major, physicsLevel, mathLevel, chemistryLevel, gpa, is_on_probation):
        self.name = name
        self.physicsLevel = physicsLevel
        self.mathLevel = mathLevel
        self.chemistryLevel = chemistryLevel
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation

    def on_honor_roll(self): # function placed inside a class, in this case, whether student is on honor roll through the level of gpa
        if self.gpa >= 3.5:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

## object.py

```
from Student import Student

student1 = Student("Jim, ", "GeoPhysics and Space", "A", "A", "B", 3.1, "False")
student2 = Student("Ann, ", "Design and Innovation, ", "A, ", "A, ", "B", 4.2, "True")
```

QUESTION: Tried  below, but isn't there a smarter way to print all students or all gpa results? - also, why does line 2 start indented with one character, doing below attempt to print?

```
print(student1.name, student1.major, student1.physicsLevel, student1.gpa, '\r\n', student2.name, student2.major, student2.physicsLevel, student2.gpa)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `__str__` method in the student class that returns a string with the formatting you want:

```
....
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}, {self.major}, {self.gpa}"
...
```

Then just loop over the students:

```
for student in (student1, student2):
    print(student)
```

Comment: Am I allowed to ask a new question here? - 'cause I also wanted to write n number of students to a csv-file? Tried to look around, but I may not yet be as smart to understand the suggestions I read about, i.e. combining aforementioned class/object context and then write result to a file. Thx, again…;o)

Comment: @user11409667, it is better you open another question separetly. Since each of them should cover just a specific problem.